# Create different data tables using for loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a task to create different subsets of the same data table as following:

```
card_1 <- tail(card_HS,-01) 
card_2 <- tail(card_HS,-02) 
card_3 <- tail(card_HS,-03) 
card_4 <- tail(card_HS,-04)
card_99 <- tail(card_HS,-99)
```

After I would have to run simple regression on each data frame and export the results:

```
reg1 <- lm(lwage ~ univ + exper + expersq + black + smsa + south, data = card_r1)
stargazer(reg1, title="Reg1", type="html")

reg2 <- lm(lwage ~ univ + exper + expersq + black + smsa + south, data = card_2)
stargazer(reg1, title="Reg2", type="html")
<...>

reg99 <- lm(lwage ~ univ + exper + expersq + black + smsa + south, data = card_99)
stargazer(reg1, title="Reg99", type="html")
```

I've tried my best, but all my attempts have failed so far. Like this one:

```
for(i in 1:99){
paste("card_", i, sep = "") <- card_HS[paste("-",i),]
}
```

Anyone have any tips? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the output in a list -

```
val <- 1:99
hmtl_list <- vector('list', length(val))

for(i in val) {
  reg <- lm(lwage ~ univ + exper + expersq + black + smsa + south, 
            data = tail(card_HS, -i))

  hmtl_list[[i]] <- stargazer(reg, title= paste0('Reg', i), type="html")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked great! Is there a way to add the out option to store the results? Like out ="C:.........\\reg1.html) and so on....

Comment: Yes, instead of assigning it to a list you can do `stargazer(reg, title= paste0('Reg', i), type="html", out = paste0('C:....\Reg', i, '.html'))`